# wget to download a link.php

Tags: wget, curl

I am having trouble finding a way to use `wget` to download a file from a link that uses `php` to point to the download.

For example, if I want to write a script to download... say superantispyware portable every day so I have a fresh copy all the time (only handy if you run windows, which I don't but I digress) the download link looks like :

> http://www.superantispyware.com/sasportable.php

I don't want the PHP file, I want the file it links to. In a browser I assume some server side magic happens to make this work. Is there an incantation I can use to emulate what my browser does? can `curl` do this?

Answer (score 7):

By default, the filename of the URL is used as the target filename. If redirection occurs, it is preferable to use the final filename. That can be accomplished with the `--trust-server-names` option of `wget`:

```
wget --trust-server-names http://example.com/file.php
```

From the manual page of wget:

> --trust-server-names
>    If this is set to on, on a redirect the last component of the redirection
>   URL will be used as the local file name.  By default it is used the last
>   component in the original URL.

If the target filename is not what you intended, you can use the `-O` (long option: `--output-document`) option as in:

```
wget http://example.com/file.php -O meh.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

The "magic" is server side, not in the browser, so you just `wget` or `curl` the url.

Comment: Murphy's Law would say I'd find the answer just after I post a question (very educational 4 hours though, I now know wget and curl better than I would without a problem like this!) This can be done with the -O (wget) or -o (curl). Following the example above-
curl -o sas.com http://www.superantispyware.com/sasportable.php 
OR 
wget -O sas.com http://www.superantispyware.com/sasportable.php 

The output file seems to need to be renamed to match the extension of what I want to download, or else it ends in .php and won't execute.

Comment: @caleb Self-education is the best. Remember to check correct answer!

Comment: This answer is just wrong