# Wget Scheme Missing

Tags: cron, wget

When I run Wget from terminal with command

```
wget targetfile.php
```

I got error "Scheme Missing". What does it is suppose to mean and how to fix it? I googled but all links I found is speaking of drupal wget. I've tried using absolute path but still not working and yield the same error. I'm trying to set up cronjob here. I follow this tutorial http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml where then it leads me to use wget.

tried

```
wget absolutePath/targetfile.php
usr/bin/wget absolutePath/targetfile.php
```

also tried using relativePath to targetfile.php by changing directory to absolutePath first.

Comment: You have to specify path to the file, like a `url`.

Comment: What do you mean by like url? I tried using absolute path already if that's what you are saying.

Comment: Can you post the path you tried, without specific ip or domian?

Comment: ok, added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php interpreter instead. So it should be

```
/usr/bin/php absolutePath/targetfile.php
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with `wget` is that you use it to download a file from a webpage directly. I had similar problems when my source webpage no longer existed. A normal wget command usually looks like this, I believe `wget http://www.example.com/filename.whatever`.
[This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99954/wget-to-download-a-link-php?rq=1) might be helpful to you.